# Same hard disk reported twice in Red Hat (SAN and multipath)

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network, multipath, hba

I use two Q-Logic HBA's on one server which have access to the same LUN. Red Hat (and gparted also) sees the LUN as two seperate disks (sda, sdb). Is this normal?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you configure multipath?

Comment: H.A. worked fine without configuration using ESXi. I'm new in SAN. I read that I must first download the HP PSP pack, where I will have the multipath software. I will do that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't configure multipathing. The most simple wat is to install Red Hat using "linux mpath" options.